# how to check if Mapkit is available or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I am building an application that is using Mapkit. I know that this is only available in IOS6. 
So I should check if this is available or not. I am using the following code.

```
  if(NSClassFromString(@"MKMapKit")) {
        // MKMapKit is available in this OS
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords =
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.097185,5.621653);

        NSDictionary *address = @{
        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey: @"Weg naar oqdffds 59",
        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey: @"Msfsf",
        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey: @"Limbusqfqsdf",
        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey: @"3670",
        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey: @"BE",
        (NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMainLabel:@"04741234567"
        };
        MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                              initWithCoordinate:coords addressDictionary:address];

        MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];
        mapItem.phoneNumber = @"0141343252";

        //current location
        MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];


        NSArray *mapItems = @[mapItem, mapItem2];

        NSDictionary *options = @{
            MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
            MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:
            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MKMapTypeStandard],
            MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey:@YES
        };

        [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];


    }else {
        NSLog(@"tot hier");
        // MKMapKit is not available in this OS
        locationController = [[MyCLController alloc] init];
        locationController.delegate = self;
        [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

But for some reason or another it always use the google method.

Can anybody help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, *MapKit* has been available well before iOS 6.

What you want to check for is `MKMapItem` (not "MKMapKit").

However, as the [documentation for `MKMapItem` explains](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011746-CH1-SW23) (with a code example):

> To determine whether a class is available at runtime in a given iOS
>   release, you typically check whether that class is nil. Unfortunately,
>   this test is not cleanly accurate for MKMapItem. **Although this class
>   was publicly available starting with iOS 6.0, it was in development
>   prior to that.** Although the class exists in earlier releases, you
>   should not attempt to use it in those releases.
>
> **To determine at runtime whether you can use map items in your
>   application, test whether the class and the
>   openMapsWithItems:launchOptions: class method exist.** That method was
>   not added to the class until iOS 6.0. The code might look like the
>   following:
>
> ```
> Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class]; 
> if (itemClass && [itemClass 
>     respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {   
>     // Use class 
> }
> ```

So this check:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"MKMapKit")) {
```

should be:

```
Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class]; 
if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
```

or:

```
Class itemClass = NSClassFromString(@"MKMapItem"); 
if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

MkMapKit is available in ios 4.3, too, probably in 3.x, too!
What is new, is (like in all Releases), some new methods of MkMapKit:

You should better check for that specific method you need
(geocoding ?=

Look into the headers of MkMapKit you are importing (if i remeber correctly: MkMapKit.h), there are Macros defining the availability
of a specifc method, depending on the ios version.